# Create multiple new variables that are calculated from existing variables

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, purrr

I'm trying to figure out how to create multiple new variables that are calculated using variables currently in my dataset

Here's some example data

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
 a1 = rnorm(100),
 a2 = rnorm(100),
 b1 = rnorm(100),
 b2 = rnorm(100),
 c1 = rnorm(100),
 c2 = rnorm(100)
)
```

Essentially, I want to create a new variable for each a, b, c pair that divides a1 by a2, b1 by b2, etc. For example:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(a3 = a1/a2)
```

The variables in my dataset don't follow these naming conventions, so I feel like I need to assign names to vectors:

```
numerators <- c('a1', 'b1', 'c1')
denominators <- c('a2', 'b2', 'c2')
```

And then creating a new variable would follow the basic convention

```
mutate(newvars = numerators/denominators)
```

But I'm stuck as to how to actually do this. Any help would be much appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to `split` the dataset into a `list` of data.frame based on the column name pattern, then `reduce` it by dividing elementwise on each pair of columns in each of the dataset and bind with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   split.default(sub("\\d+", "", names(.))) %>% 
   map_df(reduce, `/`) %>% 
   rename_all(~paste0(., 3)) %>% 
   bind_cols(df, .)
```